# width:auto in firefox is not working as intended

Tags: html, css

So, I have an image wrapped in a div (`.indexWrap`):

```
<div id = "slider">      
<div class="indexWrap">                 
        <img class="indexImage" src="">                             
       </div>
</div>
```

There are 8 of these created on page load via php within a div called `#slider`. I am using [smooth Div Scroll](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/) to display these images on the home page. Everything looks fine in Chrome, and looks ok in IE 8 and 9. Problem is in firefox. the auto width of `div.indexWrap` for each image is not setting properly. The div seems to stretch an extra 200-300px to the right. Here is the css:

```
#slider{
    position: relative;
    top:50px;
    width:100%;
    height:275px;
}
div.scrollWrapper
{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div.scrollableArea
{
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
.indexWrap{
    float:left; 
    position:relative;
    width:auto;
    height:100%;

    padding-right:50px;
    padding-left:50px;
}
img.indexImage{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:auto;
    height:100%;
}
```

Here is a link to the live version with the issue: [jasone.co](http://jasone.co)

Edit:
And on top of this on page load each `div.indexWrap` is not properly padded, but as the scrolling begins the next retrieved elements are padded correctly kind of lame. May be the cause to all this.

Comment: consider using thumbnails for preview its taking too long to load

Comment: reduced image size sources by 100px max-width. may consider smaller, the images are retrieved from a tumblr blog's api, I should probably retrieve them through ajax so the page shows something while it's showing nothing for a few seconds.

Comment: still having this issue, this is quite annoying I feel like it must be something simple that I forgot about. The identical divs containing the images are all floated and relatively positioned. I will try other techniques.

Comment: fixed the issue by getting rid of the wrapper around the image. not how a wanted it but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by getting rid of the wrapper around the image. Not how a wanted it, but it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

try adding `display: inline-block;`

Comment: unless you care about cross-browser

Answer (score -3):

Just remove...

width: auto;

//blah blah blah to fill up the max char requirement for SO, I can't believe it really needs to be this long

Comment: You can add an HTML comment instead of the comment padding

Comment: width is already default to auto, removing or including `width:auto;` shouldn't make a difference unless you had it defined already.